# Padding doesn't apply to <select> HTML tag dropdown arrow

Tags: css, jsx

I'm having a weird layout issue when using `select` tag. As you can see from the screenshot below, my padding isn't applying.

**Edit:** as correctly pointed out in the comments, the code below is part of a `React JSX` component, not standard `html`.

Specifically, the arrow that appears to the right automatically with the `<select>` tag isn't obeying the padding rules.

[image]

Here is my `CSS` for this component:

```
.textField {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
}
```

My `JSX`:

```
<select className="textField" name="states" id="states">
  <option value={defaultValue} selected disabled hidden>{defaultValue}</option>
  {options.map((option) => (
  <option onClick={()=> clickHandler(option)} value={option}>
    {option}
  </option>
  ))}
</select>
```

Wondering if this is an issue with styles applying to `<select>`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Select tags are notoriously difficult to style. Please provide HTML in questions tagged as HTML, not something from a random framework . Better still provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Good point, I edited to reflect that this is jsx not html.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide default arrow and add custom arrow image. I have updated css. you can apply this css in your code.

```css
.textField {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background-image: url('https://www.svgrepo.com/show/80156/down-arrow.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 14px 14px;
    background-position: calc(100% - 16px);
}
```

```html
<select class="textField" name="states" id="states">
    <option>defaultValue</option>
    <option>
        option 1
    </option>
    <option>
       option 2
    </option>
    <option>
        option 3
    </option>
    <option>
        option 4
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Actually I was wanting to avoid adding a custom arrow and instead dig more into why this behavior is happening and how to fix it. That being said, your solution works perfectly fine and for anyone trying to get a fix out the door for this issue, your solution is probably the best to do so.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no attribute in HTML called `className` . It should be `class` .

Comment: OP is calling it html but it is actually JSX that requires using `className`

Comment: MB. I have not noticed he is using React. Questioner has added only html and css tag. And JSX is not mentioned anywhere in the question too.

Comment: Yes I understand that however it is also obviously not standard html

Comment: My mistake, I edited the question to reflect that this is jsx not html.